# matplotlib optionally autoscale axis range on the left or right

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I programmatically set the range of a matplotlib plot, optionally keeping autscaling (on either the left or the right):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
myrange = None,None
ax.set_xlim(myrange)
ax.plot(a-5,a)
plt.show()
```

This sets the range to `0 to 1` instead of my desired `-5 to 4` (autoscaling). I've also tried:

```
 ax.set_xlim(*myrange)
```

But that doesn't do any better.  I know about the `auto=True` option, but that doesn't seem to work with `left` and `right` keyword arguments.  In other words, I'd also like to be able to set the range on the left to autoscale (`-5`) and to limit it on the right to a particular value -- e.g. :  `myrange = None,3`

---

For those who might be familiar with `gnuplot`, I'm interested in the equivalent of gnuplot's:

```
set xrange [*:max]
```

or

```
set xrange [max:*]
```

syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `ax.set_xlim` after `ax.plot`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(a-5,a)
ax.set_xlim(xmin = -1.)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  It seems to destroy the autoscaling on the right -- And it seems pretty hacky to have to do something like:  `ax.set_xlim(**dict((x,y) for x,y in zip(("left","right"),myrange) if y is not None))`

Comment: On my machine with matplotlib 1.1.1, Python 2.7.3 on Windows7 it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure?  Try `left = 1` instead of `left = -100` (I'm on OS-X, matplotlib 1.1.0)

Comment: OK, I tried again and you are really right. Sorry, couldn't believe it! But, I have an example, where I put the left limit to 70000 and that works. Sorry, I can not reduce that example, because it's in a larger piece of code. I think that must be some kind of bug.

Comment: I checked this again. The problem was that you called `set_xlim` before `plot`. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes a little sense I suppose.